# Tika - Out Of memory Exception

Tags: java, image, out-of-memory, heap-memory, apache-tika

I have been working on `Tika` to extract text contents only from various files. I found a peculiar issue when I was parsing a doc file with images inside. The Image fetcher was called and it threw `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

I was trying the same in `tika-app 1.22 gui` and was getting the following exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "Image Fetcher 2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(DataBufferInt.java:75)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Raster.java:467)
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1032)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageRepresentation.createBufferedImage(ImageRepresentation.java:253)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageRepresentation.setPixels(ImageRepresentation.java:559)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageDecoder.setPixels(ImageDecoder.java:138)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.sendPixels(PNGImageDecoder.java:549)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.produceImage(PNGImageDecoder.java:470)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:269)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
Exception in thread "Image Fetcher 0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(DataBufferInt.java:75)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Raster.java:467)
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1032)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageRepresentation.createBufferedImage(ImageRepresentation.java:253)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageRepresentation.setPixels(ImageRepresentation.java:559)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageDecoder.setPixels(ImageDecoder.java:138)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.sendPixels(PNGImageDecoder.java:549)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.produceImage(PNGImageDecoder.java:470)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:269)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
Exception in thread "Image Fetcher 1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(DataBufferInt.java:75)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Raster.java:467)
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1032)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageRepresentation.createBufferedImage(ImageRepresentation.java:253)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageRepresentation.setPixels(ImageRepresentation.java:559)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageDecoder.setPixels(ImageDecoder.java:138)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.sendPixels(PNGImageDecoder.java:549)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.produceImage(PNGImageDecoder.java:470)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:269)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
```

My questions are:

1. Why would I need to fetch the image for text only extraction from
   documents?
2. How do I configure `Tika` to skip fetching images
   like in this case. I don't wish to increase my heap memory to solve
   this instead gracefully skip the images.

---

Edit: I am reading a file as stream and wrapped it as tikaInputStream and then opened an outputStream to write the result in another file.

```
        outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
        WriteOutContentHandler writeOutContentHandler = new WriteOutContentHandler(outputWriter, writeLimit);

        AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();  
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

        parser.parse(inputStream, writeOutContentHandler, metadata);
```

I have attached the file which I used for testing and got the following exception:

```
org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Unexpected RuntimeException from org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser@4f209819
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:282)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:143)
    at tika.Tikaimpl.main(Tikaimpl.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Block 96991 not found
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.getBlockAt(POIFSFileSystem.java:434)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.readBAT(POIFSFileSystem.java:406)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.readCoreContents(POIFSFileSystem.java:359)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:239)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:172)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:121)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Position 49659904 past the end of the file
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.nio.FileBackedDataSource.read(FileBackedDataSource.java:88)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.getBlockAt(POIFSFileSystem.java:432)
    ... 9 more
```

[File](https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0040403916302064-mmc1.doc) used for testing.

Comment: How do you normally call Apache Tika? Tika App? Tika Server? Java code, if so what code? etc

Comment: I guess i mentioned tika app 1.22 jar that is run in gui mode.

Comment: The GUI mode is really only intended for testing and demos! You need to switch to something else (Java, CLI, Server etc) to get proper control

Comment: Still facing the issue even in code, I set a write limit of 10mb.

Comment: Any solution you found? I am having same issue

Answer (score 0):

Increase the size of -XX:MaxPermSize upto 1GB